# How to enumerate the rows giving the same numbers to the rows from the same groups in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to transform my dataframe

```
  Number Value
1      1    34
2      1    56
3      3    23
4      3    45
5      3    12
6      7     4
7      7     9
```

so that the observations are continuously numbered and the observations with the same old numbers have the same new numbers:

```
  Number Value
1      1    34
2      1    56
3      2    23
4      2    45
5      2    12
6      3     4
7      3     9
```

Is there a command in R which enumerates the rows giving the same numbers to the rows from the same groups?

Comment: Try `data$Number <- with(data, match(Number, unique(Number)))` or `as.integer(factor(data$Number))` or `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, Number := .GRP, Number]`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, it works